# Are we allowed to post question on server plugins?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

I know you are allowed to ask about mods in Minecraft (there are even specific tags for it), however does this extend to server plugins? I'm not talking about help coding them or help with small plugins no one knows, but more about asking questions on popular plugins, like McMMO. An example question could be:

### How does Minecraft Fishing rod Enchants effect McMMO junk/treasure probabilities?

I'm no expert on other games that also have server side plugins (that are different to mods), however would a similar policy apply to them? (i.e. would questions about "X" well know plugin be allowed?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, questions about server plugins are perfectly on topic. After all, they are more or less just mods in a slightly different format. The question you want to ask looks okay to me.

There are a few caveats though:

1. We don't answer questions about creating server mods, as you've already noted.
2. Questions asking for technical support for a modded game are also off-topic, since we can't accurately diagnose whether its conflicting mods or computer hardware or something else causing the issue.

Keep these limitations in mind, and you should be fine.